The purpose of MediaButtonReceiver in Android API 21+
When handling mediaButton events originating from remote controls or headsets, the Android documentation states here:

On Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher, Android automatically dispatches media button events to your active media session

So if the active MediaSession picks up media button events, why would it still be necessary for an API 21+ app to register a MediaButtonReceiver and let your MediaBrowserService (or other Service) listen to MEDIA_BUTTON intents?
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>


Further down it says: "If you want to use media buttons in systems earlier than Android 5.0 you must include the MediaButtonReceiver in your manifest".
